# Django showing 500 Internal Server Error on HTTPS

Tags: django, ssl, https, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am getting the following error in `error.log` in apache2 directory :   `Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`.

I have the following configuration in my `example-instance.conf` :

```
 ErrorDocument 404 "/error-pages/404.html"
 ErrorDocument 500 "/error-pages/500.html"
 ErrorDocument 403 "/error-pages/403.html"

 # Change the following three lines for your server

 ServerName example.app
 SetEnv HTTP_HOST "example.app"
 ServerAdmin admin@example.app

 SetEnv LC_TIME "en_GB.UTF-8"
 SetEnv LANG "en_US.UTF-8"

 SSLEngine on

 SSLCertificateFile "path/to/certificate"
 SSLCertificateChainFile "path/to/certificate"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "path/to/private_key"

 WSGIScriptAlias /app "path/to/wsgi_prod.py"

 # Comment next 2 lines if using older Apache than v2.4
 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
 WSGIDaemonProcess instance1_wsgi python-path="__PATH_TO_ENV_SITE-PACKAGES_FOLDER__"
 WSGIProcessGroup instance1_wsgi

 # Comment 'Require all granted' for older Apache than v2.4

 <Location "/">
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymLinks
 </Location>

 Alias /static/ "path/to/static/"
 Alias /app/static/ "path/to/static/"
 <Directory "path/to/static/">
   Require all granted
   Options -Indexes
 </Directory>

 Alias /data/ "path/to/data/"
 <Directory "path/to/data/">
   Require all granted
   Options -Indexes
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-instance-error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-instance-access.log combined
```

The site worked perfectly fine on `http` however on configuring it for `https`, I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` on '/app' subdirectory where my Django app lies. The landing page of the site is perfectly fine, which indicates that `https` is working.

Comment: Can you provide an output of your package versions and perhaps an exact paste of the error message you receive on the 500 page?

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator ... 

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 443

Comment: python2 - 2.7.15, apache - 2.4.29, django - 1.11.24, openssl - 1.1.1, mod_wsgi - 4.5.17

Comment: Maybe because http and https use different ports.

Comment: I have the following config in Virtual Host section : `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: Comment out the `ErrorDocument 500 "/error-pages/500.html"` part and post what happens

Comment: I got this - 'Internal Server Error ... Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 443' after commenting out that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `pip install psycopg2-binary` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem :/ Only option for now was to turn off mod_ssl and get back to port 80 in config file.

Strange is that i have Debug = True in settings.py but when app crashes i receive only error 500 page from apache.